# Is there a way to initialize fields out of constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor

I seem to remember some kind of short hand way to initialize fields of a class sent to a constructor, something like:

```
 Class A {
    int n;
    public A(int N) : n(N) {}
 }
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be C++, but you tagged your question C#.  C# has no notion of initialization lists, you simply assign your fields in the constructor.  You can however chain constructors or call a base class constructor in a similar manner

```
// call base class constructor before your own executes
public class B : A
{
    public B(int whatever)
        : base(something)
    {
        // more code here
    }
}

// call secondary constructor
public class B : A
{
    private int _something;

    public B() : this(10) { }

    public B(int whatever)
    {
        _something = whatever;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it possible in C#, that's why the tag is there.

Comment: @Thepoosh: Yeah, writing `someVar = someArg` is so much more tedious than writing `someVar(someArgs)`.  You must be joking to say that C# requires more boilerplate code than C++... must be...

Comment: @EdS. no worries, it was a bad joke. sorry for my faul humor :)

Comment: @Thepoosh: Nah, I kind of figured it was, just wasn't sure :D

Comment: Actually c# does have field initialization lists, so long as they are accessible the calling code.. See the answer by jleruohep.

Comment: @ajawad987: That's not an initialization list, it is shorthand for constructing an object with a paramaterless constructer and then assigning each field.

Answer (score 4):

There is easy way to initialize class fields after constructor like this:

```
public class A
  {
    public int N;
    public string S;
    public A() {}
  }

  class B
  {
     void foo()
     {
        A a = new A() { N = 1, S = "string" }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, What I was looking for is in the accepted answer, but this is also great.